# VBA Code occasionally counts more cells than it should

Tags: excel, vba, count

I stole some code from elsewhere before adjusting it to suit my needs. I needed to make a KPI form provide a percentage of submitted scores taking into account empty, blacked out cells that were not to be included in the percentage.

The code I have repurposed counts the number of blacked out cells, works alongside another bit of code that counts total selected cells and then uses COUNTA() against the resulting total not black value to provide a final percentage, however the CountBlack code I have seems to occasionally increase the number of cells counted by 2 inexplicably. See below.

```
Function CountBlack(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    CountBlack = 0
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            CountBlack = CountBlack + 1 ' adds 1 for each that meets criteria
        End If
    Next datax
End Function

Function CountAll(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    CountAll = 0
    For Each datax In range_data
        CountAll = CountAll + 1 'adds one for each counted
    Next datax
End Function
```

Image of spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's the `CountBlack` that's overcounting? It looks too simple to get anything wrong. Is it possible the COUNTA() is counting cells that contain a value but are also blacked out?

Comment: I tested it below the percentage result, separating it down into each of the 3 parts and confirmed that it was CountBlack. I have checked for hidden cells, and the like and cannot figure out where the extra count is coming from.

Comment: Also, in case you have some.. beware of what's happening with merged cells. Your CountBlack will count all cells within a single merged cell separately - which might explain an overcount compared to the human eye.

Comment: This was also taken into account, merged cells were re-separated and dealt with accordingly.

Comment: Image added, range is "H2:H46"

Comment: H2:H46 is where on that screenshot?  Are you calling that function in VBA, or on a worksheet?  Please show exactly how it's called.

Comment: Image has been updated.

Comment: Add this `Debug.Print datax.Address` before the `CountBlack = CountBlack + 1` line and see which cells are being counted

Comment: Your functions will not recalculate if you colour a cell black, or remove the black colouring. Perhaps that is the issue? (BTW  your `CountAll` function is unnecessarily complicated - you just need `range_data.cells.countlarge` without a loop.)

Comment: How and When do the cells turn black?

Comment: Black cells are there as a result of KPIs not being scheduled for the relevant location that month, so that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try debugging the issue by reviewing *what* it is counting. Add a Debug.Print line like so:

```
Function CountBlack(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    CountBlack = 0
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            CountBlack = CountBlack + 1 ' adds 1 for each that meets criteria
            Debug.Print datax.Address ' output address of black cell
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

And then review the list of 18 cells it thinks are black. Hopefully that will tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, after adding the debug line it seemed to fix itself so god knows what was happening.